# Why isn't MVC4 looking in the Area-specific Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas, mvc-editor-templates, display-templates, attributerouting

Trying to move some code from an MVC3 project to an MVC4 project, and running into this issue. There are some `DisplayTemplates` within an area, like so:

```
MVC Project
--Areas
----Identity
------Controllers
--------MyHomeController.cs
------Models
--------MyHomeViewModel.cs
--------MyEmailAddress.cs
------Views
--------Shared
----------DisplayTemplates
------------MyEmailAddress.cshtml
----------MyHome.cshtml
--------ViewStart.cshtml
--------Web.config
------IdentityAreaRegistration.cs
```

The `MyHomeController` has an action which returns the `MyHome.cshtml` view, strongly-typed to the `MyHomeViewModel`. MyHomeViewModel contains an `IEnumerable<MyEmailAddress>` property. Within the 'MyHome.cshtml' file, I have the following:

```
@foreach (var email in Model.Emails)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => email)
}
```

However, this is not rendering the MyEmailAddress.cshtml Template. Same results with both of the following:

```
@foreach (var email in Model.Emails)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => email, "MyEmailAddress")
}

@foreach (var email in Model.Emails)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => email, "~/Areas/Identity/[rest of path]/MyEmailAddress.cshtml")
}
```

However, if I move the `MyEmailAddress.cshtml` file into the root web project's `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder, it **does** render using this template.

For some reason, the DisplayFor HtmlHelper is either not looking in the area-specific Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates folder, or it is looking for something else in that folder.

What am I doing wrong? This works in MVC3, but I can't seem to get it right in the MVC4 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I immediately found my own answer right after giving up and posting this question.

The `MyHomeController` was using [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/). I discovered that if I went to the URL `/Identity/MyHome/Action`, the `DisplayTemplate` was being successfully chosen. However for my custom route, `/my/home`, it was not. Adding the following attribute to MyHomeController fixed this:

```
[RouteArea("Identity")]
public class MyHomeController : Controller
```